# Unable to set Weight property of the Borders class

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Weird issue I'm having.

My excel file had:
6 Sheets
11 buttons on 4 of the sheets
3 buttons on 1 of the sheets
and 0 on the first sheet

My workbook is currently protected using

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    wsArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet7")

    For Each wsArray In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wsArray.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next wsArray
End Sub
```

I added one more activex button to the first page which is searches for a value on a separate workbook and if that value is found, then it goes back to the first workbook and adds a border around that value it found a match for.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rr23WS As Worksheet, rrCell As Range
Dim rrCheck As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim rrMatch

Set rr23WS = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("October")
Set rrCheck = rr23WS.Columns(1)

For r = 1 To 4

    For Each rrCell In Worksheets("RACK " & r).Range("C6:N13").Cells
    
        rrMatch = Application.Match(rrCell, rrCheck, 0)
    
            If Not IsError(rrMatch) Then
            
                rrCell.Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 192)
                rrCell.Borders.Weight = xlThick
                
            End If
    
    Next rrCell
    
Next r

End Sub
```

The code ONLY works when I unprotect every single sheet where I'm searching the ("C6:N13") range.

If I close the workbook and open it again (in it's automatic protected mode), it does not work.  It gives me the error of "Unable to set the Weight property of the Borders class".  However, all the other macro buttons I have on the other sheets work just fine while the workbook is protected.

I've tried setting the `Borders.Color = xlThin` before `xlThick` but that didn't work, also tried `xlHairline` and no go with that.
Tried setting the `Application.EnableEvents = False` then back to True and that didn't work.

I'm using excel 2016 and have come across a lot of things saying this is a bug and tried other work arounds that worked for some people, but not myself.

Can someone please shed some light on what the heck is happening?!

EDIT:  This worked, but WHY?!  I'm not even selecting the range on the correct sheet.  But having the `Range("C6:N13").Select` is a must, otherwise it doesn't work.

[image]

I can change the range to just 1 random cell also and it works just fine.  Must be reading several different border styles and not knowing which one to change from?

So selecting a random range, changing it to a definitive style to read?

Comment: So is `rr23WS` in `ThisWorkbook` or in another one?

Comment: Does it work when you replace the enumeration with the value for it instead?

Comment: @ BigBen rr23WS is the separate workbook.

Comment: @braX  so  rrCell.Borders.Weight = 4 

It doesn't seem to unless the syntax for that is incorrect

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Excel 365.

Comment: It has to be something with the protection code, right?  That would explain why it's working when I unprotect everything.  

However, doesn't explain why all the other macros work just fine while protected.

It makes 0 sense.

Comment: It is weird IMO to use an array and a `For Each` loop like that but seems to work. I'd use the sheet codenames to be honest and just loop the array, instead of looping the `Worksheets` collection.

Comment: @BigBen    Interesting.  Some of the threads I read were from years ago, maybe they never went back and fixed it.

Comment: Okay so I can't get this to work, I must be doing it incorrectly.. I'll update post with a pic of my names and could you help my fried brain

Comment: My comment was more to your `Workbook_Open` code - did you change it? Though I doubt it'll fix the issue.

Comment: Ya, I just realized I wasn't on the correct tab when I took the screenshot.  But I'm pretty positive I set it up correctly the 2nd time around and it did not fix it

Answer (score 0):

You are not only protecting specific sheets, you are protecting all sheets. You will have to modify the code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wsArray, ws
    
    wsArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet7")

    For Each ws In wsArray
        Sheets(ws).Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work either.  Instantly gave me a "Runtime Error '9': Subscript out of range" upon opening